# Capitalize the first letter after a dot and a space

Tags: c#

I would like to capitalize the first letter after a dot and a space.

> Lorem ipsum dolor. **s**it amet consectetur adipiscing elit. **v**ivamus at lobortis mauris. **d**uis eu magna ornare.

This should be like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor. **S**it amet consectetur adipiscing elit. **V**ivamus at lobortis mauris. **D**uis eu magna ornare.

How can I do this in the C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Regular Expression to achieve this:

```
string text = "Lorem ipsum dolor. sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. vivamus at lobortis mauris. duis eu magna ornare.";

text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=\.\s*)\p{Ll}", m => m.Value.ToUpper());

Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Output:

> Lorem ipsum dolor. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at
> lobortis mauris. Duis eu magna ornare.

Also remember to add the Regex namespace:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Comment: Side note: I'd rather use `"(?<=\.\s*)\p{Ll}"` pattern, `\s*` for any number of white spaces (say, spaces, nobreaing spaces, new lines) and `\p{Ll}` is any letter in low case.